# How to get an element which starts with a pattern from XML array using xpath 1.0?

Tags: xml, xpath, header, element, startswith

The following XML:

```
<Headers>
    <string>Date:Fri, 12 Feb 2016 13:37:00 GMT</string>
    <string>Location:https://abc/1</string>
</Headers>
```

How to get the value from the **location** header (e.g. https://abc/1)?

I've tried XPath 1.0 below without result.

```
//Headers[starts-with(/string,'Location:')]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the leading `/` from `/string`, or add a `.` before it :

```
//Headers[starts-with(string,'Location:')]
```

That will make the expression relative to current `Headers` context. Otherwise it means root element `string`, which, I believe, is not what you actually want.

Another problem is, that `starts-with()` expects singular value as parameter. When `Headers` has multiple `string` child, only the first `string` will be evaluated. You can use the following expression to fix it :

```
//Headers[string[starts-with(.,'Location:')]]
```

---

**UPDATE :**

To return portion of the text after `"Location:"`, you can use `substring-after()` :

```
substring-after(//Headers/string[starts-with(.,'Location:')],'Location:')
```

Comment: I'm not sure the updated answer is correct, that one just returns the whole Headers element?

Comment: Or maybe : `substring-after(//Headers/string[starts-with(.,'Location:')],'Location:')` ?

Comment: @Stef So what do you want the XPath to return actually i.e the `<string>` element or the inner text of `<string>`, if not `<Headers>`?

Comment: Return value should be "Location:http s://abc/1" or better "http s://abc/1".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103334/discussion-between-stef-and-har07).

Answer (score 0):

```
substring-after(/Headers/string[starts-with(., 'Location:')], 'Location:')
```